# AAD B2C Yahoo OpenID Connect failed to create in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Asking question on behalf of others to continue troubleshooting here. Please see below question and GitHub [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10243).

I'm currently trying to use AAD B2C OpenID Auth with Yahoo, we set up the Client Id and Secret and the url of yahoo OAuth: https://api.login.yahoo.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Here is the error received from Azure portal:

> Cannot save Identity Provider: The key type 'EC' from the JSON web
>   keys endpoint 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/certs' is not a
>   supported key type.

Is it possible that Yahoo is using a different approach to the Standard and is not supported by AAD B2C yet?

Yahoo Open Id standard: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html#getting-started-setup

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38510968-aad-b2c-add-support-for-ec-key-type-to-openid-con

Comment: ^^ uservoice is dead ... https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/68600537-ae25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be currently unsupported scenario. Be aware that the OpenID Connect Identity Provider feature is still in preview. While it is in preview it may not support all features.
From what I see, Yahoo is using additional keys for signing. It also has RSA, but not only. Although the [OpenID Connect specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) (section 10.1.) states:

> The signing party MUST select a signature algorithm based on the
>   algorithms supported by the recipient.

The presence of unsupported signing key makes B2C to fail to add this IdP.

You may try using [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom), but I do not put a lot of hope it will work with custom policy either. There are samples for [G+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-goog-idp), [LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-li-idp), [Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-twitter-idp). It seems all of them conform to only using RSA for signatures.

Comment: Thank you Astaykov for explaining in more details. Hopefully someone at MS will fix this.